# Access a home server over the internet with a private WAN IP

Tags: networking, router, ssh, openvpn, remote-access

I have a Ubuntu machine running in my private network and I intend to use it as a media server. It works like a charm on my home network and I want to make it accessible over the internet.
My problem is, the **WAN IP** that I get on my router from my ISP is also a **PRIVATE IP** (part of the Class A Private IP Range). I concluded that my ISP have a private network setup themselves. So I cannot access any of my network outside the ISPs network eg. using mobile data. DDNS doesn't work and I believe an openVPN AS will be of no use either because of the same reason and and my ISP does not provide static IP services.

Is there any way that I can access my server securely. Something that I do not know of?

EDIT: I tried working with a DDNS and a VPN, but it requires an access port to my network, which I DO NOT HAVE, as my the node with public IP is under the control of my ISP. This is what I think is happening:

Internet ---> ISP (My Public IP) ----> My network (A subnet of my ISPs private network) ---> My server

Comment: You can use standard IPsec VPN and the DynDNS service (makes your IP appear Static) to do this.  I do this myself. My IP changes infrequently so I do not use Dyn DNS.

Comment: @John I tried to use no-ip before and  the IP that was synced to the service did't work. Seemed to me the ports I tried to access were closed from the ISP's gateway (and since my network sits behind that network, I cannot access those ports). Are IPsec and DynDNS different from how the usual DDNS and openVPN operate? Forgive me if it is a dumb question, I'm not a networking major in any sense :')

Comment: DynDNS is a service you purchase to allow you always use the same IP address for access to your home system.  It is not related to IPsec VPN - that is what I use.

Comment: Well, I tried something similar, it didn't work, like I said my ISP seems to have a private network setup with DHCP. My WAN IP changes every now and then and public IP seems to be the IP that my ISP have direct control of. So the IP that my DDNS service uses is actually under control of my ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISP is evidently using
[Carrier-grade NAT (CGN or CGNAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT),
so direct access from the internet is impossible.

To be directly exposed to the internet, you need to ask the ISP for a
static IP address. Unfortunately, this is often a paid option.

Comment: I kind of found a way to access it, however I'm not so sure if it secure or not. I found these point to point vpns named wireguard and tailscale, do you happen to know anything about it?

Comment: [What They Don’t Tell You About Setting Up A WireGuard VPN](https://dev.to/tangramvision/what-they-don-t-tell-you-about-setting-up-a-wireguard-vpn-1h2g).

Comment: Thank you for the tip.